# How to use aws secretsmanager secrets in kubernetespodoperator as env variable , such that the secrets is not exposed anywhere?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, amazon-eks

Consider I have 1 secrets `arn::USER` and i want to use it as `DBT_USER` in kubernetespodoperator such that pod can identify it as env variable and use it.

For other noemal env variables i can use :   `env_vars={"DBT_ENV": "uat"},`
But what about the one i have to fetch from aws secrets ?

Answer (score 0):

AWS has introduced a plugin called AWS secrets & configuration provider(ASCP) which helps you to sync AWS secrets manager secrets with your Kubernetes cluster.

The [Secrets Store CSI driver](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-aws-secrets-configuration-provider-with-kubernetes-secrets-store-csi-driver/) allows Kubernetes to mount secrets stored in external secrets stores into the pods as volumes. After the volumes are attached, the data is mounted into the container’s file system

You could also check this [public documentation](https://faun.pub/sync-aws-secrets-manager-secrets-with-kubernetes-to-expose-it-as-environment-variable-7f01c7a054a9) for guidance.